# A lightweight audio/video editor

Tags: windows, video, audio, video-editing

I am a translator and now I am working with a TV program of 25 minutes duration. They provide me the following things:

1. Video track with background music track
2. Audio track (this contains all dialogues)

My job is to watch this video with the audio track and translate its dialogue into my native language. Now I am using Steinberg Nuendo 4 on my PC to do this task. It's ok, but on my laptop (2.2 Ghz Quad Core Intel processor and 2 GB RAM, Win 8 64 bit) Nuendo is not running smoothly.

So I need a simple tool to do this work on my laptop. I need the following things in the software:

1. It can import a video track and minimum 2 audio tracks
2. Mute facility for each audio track
3. Its cursor should go to start position when I stop playback
4. It should have resizable video window
5. Customizable short keys (like arrow key for forward, space bar for play back)

Can anybody suggest a good software with these features and that works smoothly on a 2 GB RAM laptop?

Here is an image of Steinberg Nuendo, which I am using now:

[image: Steinberg Nuendo: screenshot of its interface]

Comment: I think dual-audio is an issue. But when I worked with subtitling, I had a VM in my Mac just to run [Subtitle Workshop](http://www.urusoft.net/products.php?cat=sw&lang=1), so simple and so efective.

Comment: I assume you need this for Windows 8, so I added the [tag:windows-8] tag. If not, please [edit] your question and tag/specify it accordingly.

Comment: @brasofilo No man, Subtitle workshop can't handle this. it is not supporting 2 audio tracks

Comment: @unor Yes, it is for win8

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to, you could try using [Movie Maker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows/get-movie-maker-download).

It should be lightweight enough for your purposes. I can't verify till later, but from what I remember, older versions seemed to run alright on their respective versions...

It supports [dual audio tracks](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/272955?wa=wsignin1.0) and all the others. Unfortunately, I can't verify if you can customize the keyboard shortcuts (they're listed [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/windows-movie-maker-keyboard-shortcuts)).